# Discard async result when result implements IDisposable

Tags: c#, async-await, idisposable

```
using var notNeeded = await foo();
```

`foo` returns an object which implements IDisposable but that object can be discarded immediately. What is the idomatic way to write this line?

```
using var notNeeded = await foo(); // (1) possible lint error: unused variable
using var _ = await foo(); // (2) looks clean but lives until the end of the function (which is rarely an issue)
using _ = await foo(); // (3) not legal
using (await foo()); // (4) possible lint error: possible mistaken empty statement
using (await foo()) {} // (5) looks like a mistake but actually does call Dispose() immediately
```

Are there any more elegant ways?

Comment: I would use `(await foo()).Dispose()`

Comment: Can `await foo();` return `null` ?

Comment: ^^ Plus: This seems a little smelly. I would expect foo() to not return the instance in the first place. Obviously you are only interested in its side effects.

Comment: Interesting suggestions, I quite like a combination of both comments: `(await foo())?.Dispose()`. @Fildor Yes, it does indeed look smelly. It was originally a colleague's question and I do not have access to their code (but it did make me curious!). Assume `foo` is a black box provided by a third party library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference for disposing immediately a non-needed `IDisposable` object:

```
(await foo()).Dispose();
```

...and in case it's `IAsyncDisposable`:

```
await (await foo()).DisposeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say to immediately dispose it

```cs
var notNeeded = await foo();
notNedded.Dispose();
```